# How can I put a JSON into an Array?

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, api

I have a question.

I have an JSON-Text in a variable.

How can I do it in a string array?

JSON-Query:
[JSON-Query results](https://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=Luzern&to=Dallenwil)

My Code

```
Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim s As String = wc.DownloadString("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=" & textBox1.Text & "&to=" & textBox2.Text)
```

Comment: Do you need specific data from the JSON put into an array or do you need to use multiple pieces of data?

Comment: multiple pieces. Its an application to print the depart time and the arrival time

Comment: JSON is a pseudo-array itself....your question is a circular question.  Clarify, using test cases and ideal outputs to communicate your question.

Comment: Its an easy question. Tha JSON is confusingly. I want it as an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to be using different parts of the JSON you could build a model to represent the data and then deserialize into that model. For instance, you can generate a model from the JSON provided: (there are a number of services to do this online)

```
    Public Class Coordinate
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property x As Double
        Public Property y As Double
    End Class

    Public Class Station
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property score As Object
        Public Property coordinate As Coordinate
        Public Property distance As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Prognosis
        Public Property platform As Object
        Public Property arrival As Object
        Public Property departure As DateTime?
        Public Property capacity1st As Object
        Public Property capacity2nd As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Location
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property score As Object
        Public Property coordinate As Coordinate
        Public Property distance As Object
    End Class

    Public Class From
        Public Property station As Station
        Public Property arrival As Object
        Public Property arrivalTimestamp As Object
        Public Property departure As DateTime
        Public Property departureTimestamp As Integer
        Public Property delay As Integer?
        Public Property platform As String
        Public Property prognosis As Prognosis
        Public Property realtimeAvailability As Object
        Public Property location As Location
    End Class

    Public Class [To]
        Public Property station As Station
        Public Property arrival As DateTime
        Public Property arrivalTimestamp As Integer
        Public Property departure As Object
        Public Property departureTimestamp As Object
        Public Property delay As Object
        Public Property platform As String
        Public Property prognosis As Prognosis
        Public Property realtimeAvailability As Object
        Public Property location As Location
    End Class

    Public Class PassList
        Public Property station As Station
        Public Property arrival As DateTime?
        Public Property arrivalTimestamp As Integer?
        Public Property departure As DateTime?
        Public Property departureTimestamp As Integer?
        Public Property delay As Integer?
        Public Property platform As String
        Public Property prognosis As Prognosis
        Public Property realtimeAvailability As Object
        Public Property location As Location
    End Class

    Public Class Journey
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property category As String
        Public Property subcategory As Object
        Public Property categoryCode As Object
        Public Property number As String
        Public Property [operator] As String
        Public Property [to] As String
        Public Property passList As List(Of PassList)
        Public Property capacity1st As Object
        Public Property capacity2nd As Object
    End Class

    Public Class Departure
        Public Property station As Station
        Public Property arrival As Object
        Public Property arrivalTimestamp As Object
        Public Property departure As DateTime
        Public Property departureTimestamp As Integer
        Public Property delay As Integer?
        Public Property platform As String
        Public Property prognosis As Prognosis
        Public Property realtimeAvailability As Object
        Public Property location As Location
    End Class

    Public Class Arrival
        Public Property station As Station
        Public Property arrival As DateTime
        Public Property arrivalTimestamp As Integer
        Public Property departure As Object
        Public Property departureTimestamp As Object
        Public Property delay As Integer?
        Public Property platform As String
        Public Property prognosis As Prognosis
        Public Property realtimeAvailability As Object
        Public Property location As Location
    End Class

    Public Class Section
        Public Property journey As Journey
        Public Property walk As Object
        Public Property departure As Departure
        Public Property arrival As Arrival
    End Class

    Public Class Connection
        Public Property from As From
        Public Property [to] As [To]
        Public Property duration As String
        Public Property transfers As Integer
        Public Property service As Object
        Public Property products As List(Of String)
        Public Property capacity1st As Object
        Public Property capacity2nd As Object
        Public Property sections As List(Of Section)
    End Class

    Public Class Stations
        Public Property from As List(Of From)
        Public Property [to] As List(Of [To])
    End Class

    Public Class RootObject
        Public Property connections As List(Of Connection)
        Public Property from As From
        Public Property [to] As [To]
        Public Property stations As Stations
    End Class
```

And then deserialize using JSON.NET into these models. Firstly, install the NuGet package `Newtonsoft.Json` and then add an import to it:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then deserialise:

```
Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim s As String = wc.DownloadString("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=" & textBox1.Text & "&to=" & textBox2.Text)
Dim journey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(s)
```

You can now access every part of the JSON using the model. For instance:

```
journey.connections.Count <-- gives you the number of connections (4 in your example)
```

Guessing a bit at the data I believe this will give you start and end date/times of the first and last connection (i.e. the whole journey):

```
journey.connections.First().from.departure
journey.connections.Last().to.arrival
```

Answer (score 1):

The red field is for first departure Time (Not Date)

The yellow field is for first arrival Time (Not Date)

The black field is for second departure Time (Not Date)

The green field is for second arrival Time (Not Date)

The blue field is for third departure Time (Not Date)

The violet field is for third arrival Time (Not Date)

That is, what I want. How can I get this Data?

[image: My GUI]

Comment: You should actually edit your original question to add this info, and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

My entire string:

```
{"connections":[{"from":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574342820,"delay":0,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"to":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574344320,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}},"duration":"00d00:25:00","transfers":0,"service":null,"products":["S4"],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null,"sections":[{"journey":{"name":"S4 21454","category":"S","subcategory":null,"categoryCode":null,"number":"4","operator":"ZB","to":"Wolfenschiessen","passList":[{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574342820,"delay":0,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508321","name":"Luzern Allmend\/Messe","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.035078,"y":8.303309},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574342940,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:29:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574342940,"delay":1,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:30:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508321","name":"Luzern Allmend\/Messe","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.035078,"y":8.303309},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8516351","name":"Kriens Mattenhof","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.026602,"y":8.30237},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:31:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574343060,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:31:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574343060,"delay":1,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:32:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8516351","name":"Kriens Mattenhof","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.026602,"y":8.30237},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508319","name":"Horw","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.017463,"y":8.306971},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:33:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574343180,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:33:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574343180,"delay":1,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:34:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508319","name":"Horw","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.017463,"y":8.306971},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508318","name":"Hergiswil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.982608,"y":8.310167},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:40:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574343600,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:40:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574343600,"delay":1,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:41:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508318","name":"Hergiswil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.982608,"y":8.310167},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508390","name":"Stansstad","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.976253,"y":8.336336},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:44:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574343840,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:44:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574343840,"delay":0,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:44:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508390","name":"Stansstad","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.976253,"y":8.336336},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:48:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574344080,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:48:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574344080,"delay":0,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:48:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574344320,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":0,"platform":"1","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:52:00+0100","departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"walk":null,"departure":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574342820,"delay":0,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T14:27:00+0100","capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"arrival":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574344320,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":0,"platform":"1","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":"2019-11-21T14:52:00+0100","departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}}]},{"from":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574345400,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"to":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346540,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}},"duration":"00d00:19:00","transfers":0,"service":null,"products":["IR"],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null,"sections":[{"journey":{"name":"IR 2976","category":"IR","subcategory":null,"categoryCode":null,"number":"IR 2976","operator":"ZB","to":"Engelberg","passList":[{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574345400,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:23:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346180,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:24:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346240,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346540,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"2","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"walk":null,"departure":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574345400,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"arrival":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346540,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"2","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}}]},{"from":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346420,"delay":null,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"to":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347920,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}},"duration":"00d00:25:00","transfers":0,"service":null,"products":["S4"],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null,"sections":[{"journey":{"name":"S4 21458","category":"S","subcategory":null,"categoryCode":null,"number":"4","operator":"ZB","to":"Wolfenschiessen","passList":[{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346420,"delay":null,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508321","name":"Luzern Allmend\/Messe","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.035078,"y":8.303309},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346540,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:29:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346540,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508321","name":"Luzern Allmend\/Messe","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.035078,"y":8.303309},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8516351","name":"Kriens Mattenhof","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.026602,"y":8.30237},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:31:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346660,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:31:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346660,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8516351","name":"Kriens Mattenhof","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.026602,"y":8.30237},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508319","name":"Horw","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.017463,"y":8.306971},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:33:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574346780,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:33:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346780,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508319","name":"Horw","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.017463,"y":8.306971},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508318","name":"Hergiswil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.982608,"y":8.310167},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:40:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347200,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:40:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574347200,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508318","name":"Hergiswil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.982608,"y":8.310167},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508390","name":"Stansstad","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.976253,"y":8.336336},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:44:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347440,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:44:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574347440,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508390","name":"Stansstad","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.976253,"y":8.336336},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:48:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347680,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:48:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574347680,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347920,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"1","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"walk":null,"departure":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T15:27:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574346420,"delay":null,"platform":"14","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"arrival":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T15:52:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574347920,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"1","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}}]},{"from":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T16:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574349000,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"to":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T16:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574350140,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}},"duration":"00d00:19:00","transfers":0,"service":null,"products":["IR"],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null,"sections":[{"journey":{"name":"IR 2978","category":"IR","subcategory":null,"categoryCode":null,"number":"IR 2978","operator":"ZB","to":"Engelberg","passList":[{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T16:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574349000,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T16:23:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574349780,"departure":"2019-11-21T16:24:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574349840,"delay":null,"platform":null,"prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508391","name":"Stans","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.958316,"y":8.366742},"distance":null}},{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T16:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574350140,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"2","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}],"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"walk":null,"departure":{"station":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"arrival":null,"arrivalTimestamp":null,"departure":"2019-11-21T16:10:00+0100","departureTimestamp":1574349000,"delay":null,"platform":"13","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}},"arrival":{"station":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"arrival":"2019-11-21T16:29:00+0100","arrivalTimestamp":1574350140,"departure":null,"departureTimestamp":null,"delay":null,"platform":"2","prognosis":{"platform":null,"arrival":null,"departure":null,"capacity1st":null,"capacity2nd":null},"realtimeAvailability":null,"location":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}}}]}],"from":{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null},"to":{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null},"stations":{"from":[{"id":"8505000","name":"Luzern","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.050165,"y":8.310172},"distance":null}],"to":[{"id":"8508392","name":"Dallenwil","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":46.933766,"y":8.392058},"distance":null}]}}
```

Comment: You should actually edit your original question to add this info (as well), and delete this one (as well).